# iPad Acrobat Reader Plugin for Safari

Tags: ipad, pdf, safari, fdf

I’m using FDF technology to build up a PDF. The code works fine on Window and on Mac. Recently, however, I tried to connect to my application using my iPad through Safari, but the below code doesn’t work:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.fdf");
out.write(fdfContent.getBytes());
out.flush();
```

My question: Is there any way to install this plugin on my iPad?

Answer (score 2):

Safari on iPad doesn't allow plugins to be installed. If your fdf file is simple enough, just serve it as a pdf file. Then iPad/iOS will happily open it.

Otherwise you're rather screwed. The options are

1. Write to Steve Jobs so that fdf is natively supported, or plugins are allowed on iOS devices, and hope for the best. (I'm joking)
2. Write a fdf app for iOS devices, and let your users use it. A quick search on the App Store doesn't show me any app which allows opening fdf files, so it might be a business chance to you.

Comment: this is true just i've got a confirmation from Apple

Answer (score 1):

iOS’s version of Safari does not support third-party plug-ins. You’ll need to serve a generic PDF with the MIME type `application/pdf` for your content to be readable in Safari on the iPad.

Comment: But on my Mac i'm Using Safari and it works fine after installing the acrobat reader plugin

Comment: @kanso Unfortunately, "But on my Mac" doesn't mean much here, because you **can't** install plug-ins on iPad.